# Problem with Integrity continious application app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, continuous-integration, integrity

I'm trying to setup integrity for my project. Sadly, my bash-fu is poor so I need some help.
In build script I enter `rake spec`. In integrity it returns status 0 and output

> (in /home/rails/integrity/builds/builds/66)

but I know, that I should got status 1 and output (after running it manually from console):

> rails@integrity:~/integrity/builds/builds/66$
>   rake spec
>   (in /home/rails/integrity/builds/builds/66)
>   rake aborted!   No such file or
>   directory -
>   /home/rails/integrity/builds/builds/66/config/database.yml
>
> (See full trace by running task with
>   --trace)

I dont create database.yml, becouse I would like to Integrity show message about it?

For me it looks like it lost pipe.
Script is running here:
http://github.com/integrity/integrity/blob/v22/lib/integrity/builder.rb#L49
Could you tell why `rake spec` in integrity returns 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have database.yml set before you can run your tests. You can write a custom build script that will set it and then run the test. Something like:

```
namespace :ci do
  task :update_submodules do
    system("git submodule update -i")
  end

  task :copy_yml do
    system("cp /my/custom/config/path/database.yml.ci #{Rails.root}/config/database.yml")
  end

  desc "Prepare for CI and run entire test suite"
    task :build => [:environment, 'ci:update_submodules', 'ci:copy_yml', 'spec', 'cucumber:ok'] do
  end

end
```

And then put rake ci:build as integrity build script. Basically this script will copy a database.yml template before launching the tests.